# How to use try-catch syntax in Android JNI?

Tags: java-native-interface

How can I catch error in JNI ?
I am trying to convert std::string to jstring and return the value to java Code.
I am looking for a way where i can catch error thrown by "NewStringUTF" .
Please help!

```
jstring result;
try
{
    result=env->NewStringUTF(data.c_str());
}

catch (std::exception e)
{
    result=env->NewStringUTF("");
}
return result;
```

Her is my gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
   ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See `ExceptionCheck` and `ExceptionClear` in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234).

Comment: JNI calls are implemented as C calls, not C++.  They do not throw C++ exceptions.  (as of Oct 2021, anyway...) As @Michael implied, all JNI calls can *set* the *Java* exception state in the JVM.  And once a *Java* exception is set in the JVM, continuing to make JNI calls is undefined behavior.

Comment: then how can i catch the error thrown by NewStringUTF

Comment: By using the functions I mentioned in my previous comment. I.e. check if there's a pending Java execption (you can also get the actual exception if you care about that), and if so clear it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to coerce JNI exceptions to C++ exceptions you could do the following:

```
struct JNICheck {
  JNIEnv * env;
  JNICheck(JNIEnv * env) : env(env) {}
  ~JNICheck() {
    jthrowable t = env->ExceptionOccured();
    if (t) {
      env->ExceptionClear();
      throw t;
    }
  }
};
```

Now you can replace some uses of `env` with `JNICheck(env)` if you want them to generate exceptions:

```
try {
    return JNICheck(env)->NewStringUTF(data.c_str());
} catch (jthrowable t) {
    return env->NewStringUTF("");
}
```

The alternative is to subclass JNIEnv and override all methods with similar code.